# How to get this month record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am using this to get today's record.

```
$this->db->where('date(BaseTbl.createdDtm)', date('Y-m-d'));
```

How to get this month's record? Would anyone please suggest the way?

Comment: Are you using any framework? If yes then please specify it

Comment: yep, im using the latest codeigniter

Comment: check my answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only mysql you can do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE YEAR(BaseTbl.createdDtm) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND 
      MONTH(BaseTbl.createdDtm) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());
```

**EDIT**

For codeigniter

```
$this->db->where('YEAR(BaseTbl.createdDtm))', date('Y'));
$this->db->where('MONTH(BaseTbl.createdDtm))', date('m'));
```

Comment: how to get last month records?

Comment: `$last_month_timestamp=strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"); $last_month=date("m",$last_month_timestamp); $year=date("Y",$last_month_timestamp);`

Comment: it works...
    
$pm = (int) date('n', strtotime('-1 months'));
$pmy = (int) date('Y', strtotime('-1 months')); 
      $this->db->where('YEAR(BaseTbl.createdDtm)', $pmy);
      $this->db->where('MONTH(BaseTbl.createdDtm)', $pm);

Answer (score 0):

try this query it will help you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: Also need to check year. Other wise it will return data with non matching year also